# What is the name for a bidirectional scatterplot zooming tactic?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, zooming, temporal

I am seeking the name for a visualization tactic which shows axis scale magnification for both the x and y axes as the cursor over the chart moves around.

Like a chart with dygraph zoom scrolling on both dimensions yet without having the separate controls.

The chart would be like a 100,000 by 100,000 scatter plot and would show both the entire data set while showing high resolution detail within the focus zone.

What is the name for this tactic? Is there a static picture or a dynamic site to explore it?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing in matplotlib would be Zoom Window. It is not able to function quite as dynamically as is described in the question but it does allow for a small focus area in a large plot. The example in the documentation is a large scatter plot.

Read some more here: [Zoom Window Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/zoom_window.html)

Comment: The suggestion here is "directionally correct". Yes, that is the idea: viewing a data set with a large range in each dimension with two different scales of resolution.

However, I have seen at least once a network events log viewer that allowed the analyst to rapidly scroll across very long ranges of calendar time while the most recent, say, 10 minutes of activity were zoomed into detail.

This was done without split views and without scaler widgets to select the region.

The experience is like flipping through a large book seeing the detail of a page appear.